# Clarity required in creating LUIS and KB and linking them

Tags: azure, bots

I created 10KB for my 10 different process. Lets say, each KB has QNA pertaining to each processes. Now i need to create a LUIS which would identify the right intent of user and fetch an answer from right KB. Can you please clarify how this works from an architecture perspective and please help me with the steps as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide and sample project [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs).

Basically you create a LUIS app and then you use the Dispatch tool to create a local file which scans all of your knowledge bases and extracts your questions to use as something that LUIS calls [utterances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-utterance), these utterances are then used to determine the user's LUIS [intent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent) in your case which knowledge base to use. Basically the dispatch app in LUIS acts as a router. One you have created the dispatch file locally then you need to push it up to your LUIS app (`dispatch create` command).

I would recommend downloading the [sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) and running through the whole process to get a basic understanding of how everything fits together. Once you have published your LUIS app you will be able to [test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-interactive-test) it within the LUIS portal by inputting example utterances and inspecting the reply to see the intent that was selected. The documentation for the Dispatch tool is [available here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch), please note that when you update your knowledge bases (by adding new entries or alternative phrasing) after publishing your dispatch app initially you will have to [refresh your dispatch model](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#refreshing-your-dispatch-model) for these new questions/alternative phrase to have an utterance added in LUIS to that map to the correct LUIS intent - otherwise they will return the [None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent#none-intent) intent.

NB. you could hack around the need to update the dispatcher by handling the case when you get a the "None" intent back and iterating through all of your knowledge bases to request an answer for the user's query and just return the answer with the higher score (have a collection that keeps the answer from each knowledge base) but I wouldn't recommend it as you miss out on the benefits of Active learning for [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-review-endpoint-utterances) and [QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base).

Comment: Thanks Matt for your quick response. In my case,i have created 10 KB(10 process) each having multiple QnA regarding my processes. I have created a LUIS app. Now, below is my question. which option should i follow.

1) Should i create 10 intents with each intent holding multiple utterances of my questions in KB?

or

2) For each questions in KB(10* number of questions in each KB) should I be create an intent because each question is different.

Comment: Hi @Anand. You won’t have to create the LUIS intents manually. This will get taken care of as part of the [dispatch step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch) in the official Microsoft guide that I linked above. The end result will be 1 intent per knowledge base and inside each intent will contain all of the utterances (qna makes questions) for that knowledge base. I strongly suggest that you follow the guide that I linked above to trial this with the provided sample project first.

Comment: Thanks, Mate. I will try with dispatch tool once and feedback you. But the docs I come across so far refers to manually create intents and link it with FAQs in kb using editor. so little surprised that dispatch tool automatically creates intents.

Comment: See the [Bot Builder Dispatch](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/microsoft-conversational-ai-tools-enable-developers-to-build-connect-and-manage-intelligent-bots/) section on this link. There is also [this video](https://youtu.be/HfnkgaQGAWs) which goes over how to setup dispatch and what it actually does under the hood (in the final two minutes).