# How to add multiple knowledge base to a single bot in Azure portal using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-qna-maker

I have two knowledge base and I wan to use both of them for a single bot to search an answer. How can I use multiple knowledge bases.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Is it possible to use two knowledge base without LUIS in a single app?

Comment: It is technically possible but not recommended. How you could achieve this without LUIS is having a loop that iterates through all of your knowledge bases and adds the answer with the highest score from each to a collection, from this collection you could then select the answer with the highest score (or display multiple answers if this is what you want.) Going the LUIS route gives you extra flexibility in your bot if you want to handle more advanced NLP in the future with minimal refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the text from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56358359/5209435). A sample nodejs application is available in the [official repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch).

There is a guide and sample project [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs).

Basically you create a LUIS app and then you use the Dispatch tool to create a local file which scans all of your knowledge bases and extracts your questions to use as something that LUIS calls [utterances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-utterance), these utterances are then used to determine the user's LUIS [intent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent) in your case which knowledge base to use. Basically the dispatch app in LUIS acts as a router. One you have created the dispatch file locally then you need to push it up to your LUIS app (`dispatch create` command).

I would recommend downloading the [sample app](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) and running through the whole process to get a basic understanding of how everything fits together. Once you have published your LUIS app you will be able to [test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-interactive-test) it within the LUIS portal by inputting example utterances and inspecting the reply to see the intent that was selected. The documentation for the Dispatch tool is [available here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch), please note that when you update your knowledge bases (by adding new entries or alternative phrasing) after publishing your dispatch app initially you will have to [refresh your dispatch model](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#refreshing-your-dispatch-model) for these new questions/alternative phrase to have an utterance added in LUIS to that map to the correct LUIS intent - otherwise they will return the [None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-intent#none-intent) intent.

NB. you could hack around the need to update the dispatcher by handling the case when you get a the "None" intent back and iterating through all of your knowledge bases to request an answer for the user's query and just return the answer with the higher score (have a collection that keeps the answer from each knowledge base) but I wouldn't recommend it as you miss out on the benefits of Active learning for [LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-review-endpoint-utterances) and [QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/improve-knowledge-base).

Comment: In this example also they used only one knowledge base. Then how two knowledge bases are used?

Comment: @KailashKumawat I have edited my answer to include how this could be achieved.

Comment: I tried in Node.js as described in documentation  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js). But in dispatchBot.js file I am getting errors. Can you help?

Comment: Like when I add - `async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult) {
    switch (intent) {
    case 'l_luis':
        await this.processHomeAutomation(context, recognizerResult.luisResult);
        break;
    case 'q_sample-qna':
        await this.processSampleQnA(context);
        break;
    default:
        this.logger.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
        await context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
        break;
    }
}`. Running this gives an error - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Can you help in this.

Comment: Can you add a pastebin of the entire class please and a screenshot of where the error is.

Comment: `dispatchBot.js` file is here [link](https://notepad.pw/dispatch.js) and `app.js` file is here [link](https://notepad.pw/app.js). I tried some thing but not getting any response from Knowledge base for any question .

Comment: Check out [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch/bots/dispatchBot.js). You would replace the qnaMaker const with a collection (array) of QnAMaker objects which hold your different knowledge bases, then inside `processSampleQnA` you would get a result for each qnaMaker object in your collection, and pick the one with the highest score.

Comment: Running these bot files giving some error - `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null` in `class DispatchBot extends ActivityHandler {}`.